# Using Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html correctly in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I have no problems using Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.text but if I also use Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html I don't get an HTML email.

Are there any example of how to use Accounts.emailTemplates.resetPassword.html correctly?

Answer (score 2):

It is very simple to use - just like you would use text. See the example below, it will send the return value as the e-mail body. Works for all three: `resetPassword`, `verifyEmail`, and `enrollAccount`.

```
Accounts.emailTemplates.verifyEmail.html = function (user, url) {
    return "<h1>Thanks for signing up!</h1>"
    + " To <strong>activate</strong> your account, click the link below:\n\n"
    + url;
};
```

Still, both variants are sent as e-mail: text and html. If your e-mail client defaults to display emails as text, then you will not see the HTML flavor of the message, so make sure both `text` and `html` contain the same information.

Comment: this is not very simple at all, instead of a attribute for the type of email you have to send, you need duplicate code. Dirty